# My UITableView isn't loading any data

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to load Contacts that contain addresses to my TableView. I attempted to debug it and the NSLogs are showing that the data is there. However when I try to load it to my UITableView, it hangs on a black screen and nothing happens. The debugger shows the data is printed to console.

I am using an iOS 7 simulator for testing my project.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _contactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self getArrayOfPeople];
        NSLog(@"array: %@", self.contactsArray);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)getArrayOfPeople {
    //ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    }
    else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
        accessGranted = YES;
    }

    if (accessGranted) {
        for( CFIndex emailIndex = 0; emailIndex < nPeople; emailIndex++ ) {
            ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, emailIndex );
            //ABMutableMultiValueRef emailRef= ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
            ABMutableMultiValueRef addressRef= ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
            int addressCount = (int)ABMultiValueGetCount(addressRef);
            if(!addressCount) {
                CFErrorRef error = nil;
                ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressBook, person, &error);
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            } else {
                ABMultiValueRef address = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
                NSString *contactAddress = (__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, 0);
                NSString *name = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));

                if (name) {
                    NSMutableDictionary *contactDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                        name, @"name",
                                                        contactAddress, @"address",
                                                        nil];
                    [self.contactsArray addObject:contactDict];
                    NSLog(@"%@", self.contactsArray);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_contactsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [_contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

I hope my pasted code above will help find the "bug" thats causing my code to malfunction.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint here return [_contactsArray count]; and see if the count is returning 0. If that is the case, try calling [tableView reloadData] at the end of ViewWillAppear or in ViewDidAppear

Comment: Might sound silly: are you sure you have set the table `dataSource` to the controller?

Comment: Yes I had the delegate and datasource wired in StoryBoard

Comment: The black screen makes me think of some infinite loop, but you assure that `getArrayOfPeople` returns the intended data, don't you?

Comment: The breakpoint is never hit at __contactsArray.

Comment: Then check that `nPeople` is a reasonable number and not -1 or some extremely high integer.

Comment: be more specific about the breakpoint not hit.  What exact line?

Comment: nPeople is 6 (i used the default data in the Contacts app). I've also reset the simulator a few times. The breakpoint in - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_contactsArray count];
}
 never gets a hit

Comment: Strange. Anyway, try the fix in my answer and let me know.. I'm getting very curious.

Comment: @keeshux I've tried your solution and same issue. I removed initWithCoder and initialized my Array in ViewDidLoad and it worked. However I've been told not to add too much code in ViewDidLoad so it's obviously with initWithCoder. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I tested your code and had no issue keeping the whole thing in `initWithCoder`. Move everything back to `initWithCoder`, start the app and as soon as you detect the freeze hit the pause button on the debugger. Now on the left you should see the line the app is stopping at.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `reloadData` on your table view after you populate your array

`[myTableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `NSDictionary` items to the array, but assigning them to `cell.textLabel.text` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Try

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[_contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: i updated my code with your line and its loading to a blackscreen.

Comment: How do you create the tableView?  In Storyboard/XIB or in code?  Either way, check the delegate is set.

Comment: I used the template provided in Xcode. I CTRL click from the TableView to the UITableView then selected dataSource and delegate

Comment: I see you have implemented `initWithCoder` (which I'm not familiar with) for your ViewController, but your call to super is [super init].  Try either putting your initialisation into `init`, or changing your call to super to [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]

Comment: @pbasdf good point, `super` call is wrong. As to initializing in `init`, keep in mind that it won't be called when the view is loaded from a XIB.

Answer (score 0):

You do this:

```
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
```

before requesting access to the address book, so you get -1 and you're stuck in a very consuming loop in `getArrayOfPeople`. Move the following lines:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
```

into the `if (accessGranted)` block.

Comment: move the lines where?

Comment: At the very beginning: `if (accessGranted) { ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ... ... ... ; for( CFIndex ...`

Comment: If I move the ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL); then my block 'ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion' will say that addressBook is an unknown variable. If I move that into the accessGranted then I'll never get access granted on iOS 6+

Comment: Pass `NULL` to `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify its launch in the appDidFinishLaunching or something else that you think may have had something to do with its normal launch
Check and try following things to debug the problem.

1. If its your 1st view ,just check if you have connect view to root of Navigation controller
2. Try to remove the class from the view and check if view is loading.
3. Try to add a new view Controller without linking class and add it to your navigation controller and check if its displaying white or black screen.